# How can I generate this error

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

Please assist me in generating an error for using a "$". I am able to successfully generate the error if I enter in negative numbers but I am not able to generate an error for having a "$" sign in my withdraw/deposit input. Hope this is not a stupid question.

Everytime I think I find an answer I enter the code and a new issue pops up.

Please forgive my formatting. It's horrid and I can't correct it. Learning process.

```
private void btnDepositActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    int index = jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex();
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = df.parse(txtOpenDate.getText());
    } 
        catch (ParseException ex) 
    {
Logger.getLogger(AccountApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.setTime(date);
    accounts = new; 
  CheckingAccount(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString(),txtCustomerName.getText(),cal,au.getBalance(index));
String input = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this,"Deposit amount for account "+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString(),"Deposit to "+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString(),JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,null,null,"");
try{
        double amount = Double.parseDouble(input);
        if (amount>=0){
            double balance = accounts.deposit(amount);
            NumberFormat defaultFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
            txtBalance.setText(defaultFormat.format(balance));
            au.setBalance(index, balance);


        try { au.updateFile(au.getAccountNumber(index), 
             au.getOpenDate(index),au.getCustomerName(index), 
             au.getBalance(index));
            }                                                           
       catch (IOException ex) {
            }
        }
        else {
            NumberFormat defaultFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                    this, "Invalid deposit amount 
                   "+defaultFormat.format(amount), 
                    "Invalid deposit", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    }
```

Comment: We are here to solve the errors(problems) but you're seeking help to generate errors

Answer (score 0):

Doing a simple use of the methods in the string class will help:

```
 String x = "$123.33";
 System.out.println(x.contains("$"));
 System.out.println(x.indexOf("$"));
```